# Issue mixing variable with mixin with keyframe animation?

Tags: sass

First time using SCSS, and testing my knowledge from the Sass-Lang.com guide. According to the guide, it is possible to both set variables and use mixins to simplify your CSS.

I was coding an animation where the div is clipped from bottom to top. I used variables to set the initial and final clip-path settings, and used them while calling a mixin. Yet I get the error, 'Invalid CSS after "...slider-initial)": expected "{", was "; }"'. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<body>
  <section id='main'>
    <div id='left'></div>
    <div id='right'></div>
  <section>
</body>
```

---

```
$slider-initial: inset(0 0 0 0);
$slider-final: inset(0 0 100% 0);

@mixin slider-clip($slider-state) {
  -webkit-clip-path: $slider-state;
  clip-path: $slider-state;
  }

body {
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#main {
  height: 64vh; width: 38vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;

  border: 1vh solid black;
}

#left {
  order: 1;
  width: 4%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 46%;
  background: green;
}

#right {
  opacity: 1;
  order: 2;
  width: 4%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto; 
  margin-left: 0;

  animation-name: dropdown;
  animation-duration: 4s;

  background: red;
}

@keyframes dropdown {
    from { @mixin slider-clip($slider-initial); }
    to { @mixin slider-clip($slider-final); }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called your mixin in a wrong way:

```
@keyframes dropdown {
  from { @mixin slider-clip($slider-initial); }
  to { @mixin slider-clip($slider-final); }
}
```

In [the guide](http://sass-lang.com/guide) on sass-lang.com, you can see the following example of how to include a mixin:

```
.box { @include border-radius(10px); }
```

Applied to your case, your code should look like this:

```
@keyframes dropdown {
  from { @include slider-clip($slider-inital); }
  to { @include slider-clip($slider-final); }
}
```